# REDUX: store variables accessed via this.props are outdated but store.getState() works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, stomp

Well hello there!

I'm having some issues - that I never had before - by accessing store variables through `mapStateToProps`. Namely, they never change and always have their default value I setup in the store BEFORE changing them in any way. If I call them by `store.getState().reducer.x` my code works!

**Here's my store:**

```
export const initialState = {
    isKeyManagementWindowOpen: false
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    some: someReducer,
    settings: settingsComponentReducer
)};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : variable => variable));

export default store;
```

**settingsComponentActions.js**

```
export const TOGGLE_KEY_MANAGEMENT_WINDOW = 'TOGGLE_KEY_MANAGEMENT_WINDOW';

export const toggleKeyManagementWindow = isKeyManagementWindowOpen => {
  return { type: TOGGLE_KEY_MANAGEMENT_WINDOW, isKeyManagementWindowOpen};
}
```

**settingsComponentReducer.js**

```
export const settingsComponentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.TOGGLE_KEY_MANAGEMENT_WINDOW:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isKeyManagementWindowOpen: action.isKeyManagementWindowOpen
      });
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

One thing that may be causing issues is that I am calling `this.props` in my `websocket's` `subscribe` method.

**Key.js**

```
connectToWebsocket = ip => {
      const stompClient = Stomp.client(`url/receivekey`);
      stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 0;
      stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 0;
      stompClient.debug = () => null;
      stompClient.connect({ name: ip }, frame => this.stompSuccessCallBack(frame, stompClient), err => this.stompFailureCallBack(err, ip));
  }

stompSuccessCallBack = (frame, stompClient) => {
    stompClient.subscribe(KEY_READER_NODE, keyData => {
      if (!this.props.isKeyManagementWindowOpen) {
        this.loginWithKey(keyData.body);
      } else {
        this.addToKeyList(keyData.body);
      }
    });
  }
```

Even though I set `isKeyManagementWindowOpen` beforehand to `true` it still resolves to `false`. If I swap `!this.props.isKeyManagementWindowOpen` with `!store.getState().settings.isKeyManagementWindowOpen` the code works and it goes into `this.addToKeyList(keyData.body)`.

So, if I swap those but LEAVE every store call in `this.addToKeyList` as `this.props.` then those are all default valued too, which doesn't make sense. It only works if I swap every `this.props.` line with `store.getState()...`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...
    ...
    isKeyManagementWindowOpen: state.settings.isKeyManagementWindowOpen,
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Key));
```

As of now, my code works but I'd like to call the `props` as `this.props...` and not via `store.getState()...`. Any idea why this could happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Seems like you're using deep state

Object assign only makes shallow copies of objects. So let's try to eliminate the easiest possible cause.

```
export const settingsComponentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Then use newState instead of state below.
This will make a deep copy of your state and will always be a new object forcing your app to see it as a new prop and re-render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this, as you shouldn't directly mutate the overall state of the app, only update it if an action is triggered but spread the original state in prior to updating.

```
export const settingsComponentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.TOGGLE_KEY_MANAGEMENT_WINDOW:
      return {
        ...state,
        isKeyManagementWindowOpen: action.isKeyManagementWindowOpen
      });
    default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: So I am always mutating the state with `Object.assign`? [This](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator/) article from redux says that it just copies values and updates. I am confused.

Comment: Apologies, it doesn't directly mutate the state. But similar to Joe Lloyd's answer, Object.assign will create a  copy of the state. From my knowledge, the best practice is to use the spread `...` operator to pull in existing values before updating.
Have you tried using the spread rather than Object.assign and tested the difference in output or is it the same issue?

Comment: No problem! It is what I will try next and then report back.

Comment: I answer to the use of props vs this.props. From my memory you can only use this.props if you are using super(props). When using Redux to store our global state, we tend to just use props.
You can take it one step further and remove props by deconstructing it from mapStateToProps which has pros and cons. The Pro is that you only take the State that you want to the component rather than mapping the entire global app State, less keystrokes (more hair pulling sometimes). Cons - Readability, sometimes actually seeing the word props does help when looking through code to see where its coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that React *cannot* have updated *any* value in `this.props` by the time the next line of code has executed.

This is not actually a Redux-specific problem.  In *any* React component, triggering a state change on a line will still result in the same `props` and `state` values on the next line, because the current function is still executing and React has not re-rendered yet.